# How to populate 2nd spinner based on 1st spinner and 3rd spinner based on 2nd spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I have 3 spinners

```
<string-array name="country_array">
       <item>India</item>
       <item>Pakistan</item>
       <item>Srilanka</item>
    </string-array>

<string-array name="city_array">
       <item>Bangalore</item>
       <item>Hyderabad</item>
       <item>Delhi</item>
    </string-array>

<string-array name="area_array">
       <item>Hitech City</item>
       <item>Jubli Hills</item>
       <item>Banjara Hills</item>
    </string-array>
```

how to make dropdown?, when india is selected it should populate Bangalore, hyderabad and delhi and when hyderabad is selected it should populate hitechcity, jublihills etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: So given your example xml, how are you determining what area corresponds to what city, and what city corresponds to what country?  Your child elements don't have a reference to their parent.

Answer (score 2):

you can set a specific array to the 1st spinner and then with a function check the string selected on the spinner and give another array to the second spinner, like this:

```
String []ejemplos= { "option1", "option2", "option3"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ejemplos);
        Sp1.setAdapter(adapter);

            Sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                String item = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

                 if(item.matches("option 1")){
                     con=1;
                     checar();
                }else{
                    if(item.matches("option 2")){
                        con=2;
                        checar();
                    }

                }
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

then, the function to fill up the second spinner (sp2), something like this:

```
void checar(){
         if(con==1){
             String []ejemplos2= { "option 1", "option 2", "option 3"};
             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ejemplos2);
             Sp2.setAdapter(adapter2);
         }else{
             if(con==2){
                 String []ejemplos2= { "opcion 1"};
                 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ejemplos2);
                 Sp2.setAdapter(adapter2);
             }else{
                 if(con==3){
                     String []ejemplos2= { "opcion 1", "opcion 2", "opcion 3"};
                     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ejemplos2);
                     Sp2.setAdapter(adapter2);
                 }
             }
         }
    }//fin checar
```

and the add a listener to the second spinner like this:

```
Sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                    con2 = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                    if(con2=="opcion 1" && con==1){
                        //do something
                    }else{
                        if(con2=="opcion 2" && con==1){
                            //do something
                        }
                    }
                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
```

on the second spinner you can call the function again and set the string to the 3rd spinner and do whatever you want! hope this works for you!

see ya!